# Parse Server - Query for the latest objects but sort results in ascending order

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Using the Parse Server Javascript SDK I am trying to pull the latest 100 objects matching the query based on createdAt

The query below pulls those 100 objects but they are returned in order from newest to oldest, I would prefer to have the results return oldest to newest.

I figured a way to fix the sort client side but surely there is a way to have the server return it in the correct order?

```
    const query = new Parse.Query('Activities');
    query.limit(100);
    query.descending('createdAt');
    query.equalTo('event_objectId', event);
    return Observable.fromPromise(query.find())
      .catch(err => this.parseProvider.handleError(err));
```

Comment: Since you are ordering descending to get the first 100 results, it will be returned in this same order. You could try to do your current query as a subquery of a main query that matches the ids and return in the order you need. But it does not make any sense as would be more expensive for your database. You can also create a cloud code function to perform the query, revert the array and return it to you. But the easier way for you is to do it actually in client side and just use `Observable.fromPromise(query.find()).toArray().mergeMap(array => array.reverse())` to reverse the result.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks, I agree if there's nothing out of the box to return the results that way then it's better to do it client side. I had created a simple function to sort the results by createdAt but maybe the array.reverse() is a hair faster since it's not parsing through the objects to sort?

Comment: Yes. Since array.reverse() is a native node.js function, it is supposed to be faster.